# Bash - Automating creation of test files

Tags: bash, shell

I'm in the process of understanding shell scripting - this is my simple code for adding test files for python [unittest](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html)

I'm looking for best practice pointers, variable naming, and of course comments on structure and readability.

EDIT: Script is called by, for example

```
./create_tests.sh math tensor_add
```

```
dir_name="$1"
file_name="$2"
test_dir="test/${dir_name}"
file_in_dir="${test_dir}/${file_name}.py"

addFile() {
    if [[ -f "${file_in_dir}" ]]
    then
        echo "File already exists in directory, exiting."
        exit 0
    else
        touch "${file_in_dir}"
    fi
}

if [[ -d "${test_dir}" ]]
then
    echo "Directory already exists, adding the file to this directory."
    addFile
else
    echo "Directory and __init__.py created."
    mkdir "${test_dir}"
    touch "${test_dir}/__init__.py"
    addFile
fi
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Add a shebang.
2. Keep naming consistent, I personally prefer and follow [Google's style guide](https://google.github.io/styleguide/shellguide.html#s7-naming-conventions); you may use a different guide if available.
3. Try to make your script POSIX compliant, for a wider target reach (no need to rely on `[[` expression from bash)
4. Define a function to create the test directory.
5. Use [shellcheck](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck).
6. The `echo "Directory and __init__.py created."` should happen **after** the creation has happened.
7. Use `mkdir -p` to allow for nested directories to also be created (if needed).
8. Let script throw error and stop as early as possible on errors. This is achieved with [`set -e`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19622198/1190388).

---

Together:

```
#!/bin/sh

set -e

dir_name="$1"
file_name="$2"
test_dir="test/${dir_name}"
file_in_dir="${test_dir}/${file_name}.py"

add_file() {
    if test -f "${file_in_dir}"
    then
        echo "File already exists in directory, exiting."
        exit 0
    else
        touch "${file_in_dir}"
    fi
}

create_dir() {
    mkdir -p "${test_dir}"
    touch "${test_dir}/__init__.py"
    echo "Directory and __init__.py created."
}

[ ! -d "${test_dir}" ] && create_dir "${test_dir}"

add_file
```

The chunk of variable declarations (`dir_name`, `file_name` etc.) could also be localised to functions.

Comment: You missed "extract common lines from `if`/`else`" from the list - though you've demonstrated in your reworked code.

Comment: Thank you for your brilliant advice. One question: what is the difference between the double brackets and single brackets in my contra your implementation? Does it have to do with POSIX compliance?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/669452/2002471 explains why double brackets are a good thing.  Striving for POSIX-compliance after bash and Linux has taken over the world is an interesting prioritization.  I'd hope that code readability and maintainability are more important these days.  Going from `if [[` to `if test` makes sense to people who understand how shell if's work, but I'd say it makes it less readable and intuitive for most folks.